# Arithmetic sequence within an array using doc.write to display Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

So the objective is to make an arithmetic sequence starting 7 with difference of 9. So 7, 16, 25, 34 etc.

You have to do this 20 times and make a one column table that autogenerates the rows per number using document.write() to print it.

I believe I understand to make an array of 20 and input the math within the array. So this is what I have so far,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Javascript Arithmetic Sequence</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

</head>
<body>

<script type ="text/javascript">
var result =[20];

for (var a = 7; a + 9; a++) {
    document.write("<table>"+
            "<tr>"+
            "<th> Arithmetic Sequence of 7</th>"+
            "<td>"+ result+"</td>"+
            "</tr>"+
            "</table>");
}
</script>


<p>Question 1: You would need to change the array length.</p>
<br>
<p>Question 2: You use document.write() to display HTML document content and not pop up as a button/alert using alert().</p>



</body>
</html>
```

The problem is, nothing shows on my HTML website and the JS validators keep saying document.write() can be used as an "eval" (which I don't understand what that means). I've scanned my chapter up and down, googled some advice (which goes way outside what the chapter is about). Looking to see if anyone can spot where I might be wrong or give advice on what I need to adjust.

Thanks.

Comment: Replace commas with + for concatenation and you are missing opening table tag.

Comment: So you mean like,
```
 document.write("<table>",
   "<tr>",
   "<th> Arithmetic Sequence of 7</th>",
   "<td>"+ result+"</td>",
   "</tr>",
   "</table>");
```

Comment: All comas replace with +

Comment: Only tr table row should be inside the for loop, table tags should be outside in plain html.

Comment: So i replaced all the commas with +, but my webpage just stays loading and the validator doesn't say anything. So i can't see the results. I'm going to place my entire HTML to see if something outside it is wrong.

Comment: You may want to google for loops in JavaScript, second part where you have a + 9 should be a condition like a < 20 so it will loop until a is incremented to 20.

Comment: I'm getting closer, I changed up the for loop and table tag locations, which I'll show in the final answer. But now I just have to make one column with 20 different rows of the answer (that autogenerates on its own and not hardcoded). Think I have an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Played around with it and finally got the answer. Thanks everyone who helped too!

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
var table = "<table border =1><tr><th>Arithmetic Sequence of d=9</th></tr>";
var result = 7 ;

for (var count = 0; count <20; count++) {
    result = result + 9;
    table+="<tr><td>"+ result +"</td>",
    "</tr>";
            
}
table+="</table>";
document.write(table);
</script>
```